# how to access methods of one object in other module?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using this statement in my router.js file.

```
var script = ('./script');
router.get('/getCustomer/:id',function (request, response) {
console.log('get method called.......');
script.getSingleCustomer(mongo.DATABASE, response);
});
```

and in my script.js

```
var Customer = require('./customerModel'); //my schema is defined in this script
module.exports = {
getSingleCustomer : function(database, request, response){
    // var user = new Customer({
    //     _id: request.params.id
    // });
database.collection('customer').findOne({}, function (error, results) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            response.json({statusCode: 400, statusData: 'The customer is not registered...', responseData: [results]});
        }
        console.log(results);
        response.json({statusCode: 200, statusData: 'Success', responseData: [results]});
    });
  }
};
```

Right now I am not implementing any id based query, I just need to access the database and send the result to android app and I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
at C:\Users\chhat\Upcomers Tech\customer\script.js:17:21
at handleCallback (C:\Users\chhat\Upcomers Tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
at C:\Users\chhat\Upcomers Tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1417:5
at handleCallback (C:\Users\chhat\Upcomers Tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
at C:\Users\chhat\Upcomers Tech\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:682:5
at handleCallback (C:\Users\chhat\Upcomers Tech\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:171:5)
at nextFunction (C:\Users\chhat\Upcomers Tech\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:682:5)
at C:\Users\chhat\Upcomers Tech\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:593:7
at queryCallback (C:\Users\chhat\Upcomers Tech\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:232:18)
at C:\Users\chhat\Upcomers Tech\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:469:18
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Please help me to send the response from the script.js.
I am developing a node.js server with mongodb for android app, so suggest me some server design structure, as I am new in backend development.

Comment: you can use node.js framework LoopBack to easily create REST APIs with little coding. https://loopback.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function with two arguments

```
script.getSingleCustomer(mongo.DATABASE, response);
```

But the function expects 3

```
getSingleCustomer: function(database, request, response)
```

So `request` will hold what actually is the `response`, and `response` will be `undefined` in `getSingleCustomer()`.
To fix that, either don't make the function expect `request` (preferably, as you don't use it in the function either way

```
getSingleCustomer: function(database, response)
```

Or call it with three arguments (senseless in this case).

```
script.getSingleCustomer(mongo.DATABASE, request, response);
```

---

And fix the typo in `function(databse, response)`, it's `database`

Comment: Thanks bro. It worked... and can u suggest me how organize the files on the server i.e. the architecture of the server. Thanks